# Laravel Sail Refusing MySQL connection

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, laravel-sail

There are no less than 1,000 threads on the interwebs about Laravel Sail and getting the "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused" error.  I have tried just about every relevant suggestion and after spending about 45 hours on this, cannot get ANYWHERE with Sail/Docker.

I installed Sail on a pre-existing project using:

```
php artisan sail:install
php artisan sail:publish
```

In Ubuntu (running Windows WSL2): I've tried:

```
sail build --no-cache
sail up -d
```

But alas, still:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from...

At one point, I was able to access the mysql cli and verify there was a database with the correct name, but the HTTP requests just weren't being accepted.  However, after reinstalling sail a few times and changing environment variables, I can no longer do this either, as I get the mysql cli error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Here's my .env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=somedb
DB_USERNAME=someuser
DB_PASSWORD=somepass
```

Here's my docker-compose:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./docker/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-redis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    memcached:
        image: 'memcached:alpine'
        ports:
            - '11211:11211'
        networks:
            - sail
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
    sail-redis:
        driver: local
```

Comment: Can you share all your env file? Forward ports etc. Also are you trying ti reach via docker or from your local machine?

Comment: `APP_NAME="some app"
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:NGKzLpnOkKdFJfdPj6aqCi9L6RYpWeA2lab/a4C3Rd4=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://app.devel

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=somedb
DB_USERNAME=someuser
DB_PASSWORD=somepass

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
MEMCACHED_HOST=memcached`

I hit a character limit but nothing below this really matters.  I was accessing "localhost" in browser when running docker.

Comment: Is your forward db port 3306?

Comment: FORWARD_DB_PORT is not assigned in .env, so it takes the default 3306 set in docker-compose.

Answer (score 4):

In file .env change `DB_HOST=mysql` to `DB_HOST=host.docker.internal`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Whatever it did it did worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

just change image_name like:

**image: "mysql:8.0"** and change as  **DB_HOST=mysql**

run **sail up -d** command it works